# get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given Laravel

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-6

Estoy utilizando el paquete yajra/laravel-datatables

Intento utilizar Datatables en laravel para mejorar el tiempo de respuesta, sin embargo
cuando intento enviar la solicitud a la vista me retorna el error get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

Si hago un DD a la consulta me retorna un archivo JSON o ARRAY(Tanto con los 2 me da el error), lo anexo

```
//Este es el codigo de mi consulta
        $datas= Referred::where('user_id','=', $referred)->select('slug_id','created_at')->get()->toJson();
```

cuando hago un DD retorna lo siguiente:

```
"[{"slug_id":44,"created_at":"2020-11-08 19:52:36"},{"slug_id":74,"created_at":"2020-11-08 19:53:43"}]"
```

Y eso esta bien, porque me trae los datos de los campos slug_id y created_at para mostrar con DataTables. pero claro, en el
datable de manera ordenada para poder anexarle mas botones, pero eso es otra historia.

sin embargo cuando mando la solicitud asi:

```
return Datatables::of($datas)->make(true);
```

Me retorno el error get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given Laravel

Si emito la data sin pasar por JSON, es decir un array, me retorna lo siguiente en la vista:

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":2,"recordsFiltered":2,"data":[{"slug_id":44,"created_at":"2020-11-08 19:52:36"},{"slug_id":74,"created_at":"2020-11-08 19:53:43"}],"input":[]}
```

Y sigue estando bien, porque es la data que necesito(slug_id y created_at), pero no logro agregarla al dataTable, asi lo intento hacer funcionar en la vista:

```html
   @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container justify-content-between">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header justify-content-between">Cliente
               </div>
                <table id="ref" class="table table-bordered data-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">ID</th>
                            <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                        </tr>                    
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    @push('scripts')
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
        oTable = $('#ref').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "{{route('referreds.edit')}}",
            "columns": [
                {data: 'array[, ].slug_id', name: 'slug_id'},
                {data: 'array[, ].created_at', name: 'created_at'},
              
            ]
        });

     
    });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Doy por hecho que los modelos y las rutas no tienen problemas, porque me redirigen bien. si las necesitan me indican y edito

Sin utilizar dataTables logro enviar la información a la vista y arreglarla con un foreac, pero
quiero utilizar esa tecnologia para dar maor velocidad.

Agradecido por su ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: ¿Estás usando [este paquete](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)?

Comment: Si, estoy usando ese paquete

Answer (score 0):

Aquien le toque un problema similar, ese error de get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given puede suceder porque tu consulta viene sin datos o mal estruturada(En mi caso ya estaba recibiendo la infomacion y el paquete que utilizo se encarga de lo demas).

Por lo tanto asegúrate con un DD o cualquier log que este recibiendo datos para rellenar el datatable.

Ahora, el error de solo recibir un JSON en la vista. Si quiere utilizar AJAX tienes que tener una ruta declarada para que AJAX consuma los recursos y los muestre en tu vista, así que, declare 1 ruta para el AJAX y el otro para mi vista.

```
//Vista de Referidos admin
Route::get('ref/list', 'ReferredController@usersList')->name('ref/list');//consulta AJAX
Route::get('referreds', 'ReferredController@index')->name('referreds.index');
```

Despues en mi controlador solo rellene:

```
 public function index()
{
   return view('referreds.index');

}

/**
 * Devuelve el listado en JSON de los usuarios
 *
*/
public function usersList(User $user, Request $request)
{

    $data = User::get(['id','email','name','id_slug']);
    return Datatables::of($data)
    ->make(true);
    //dd($referreds);
}
```

Y al final solo me asegure de tener la cantidad de celdas solicitadas en la respuesta AJAX

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#task').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{{route('ref/list')}}",
        "columns": [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'id_slug', name: 'id_slug'},
            {data: 'btn',orderable:false, searchable:false },

          
        ]
    });

 
});
</script>
```

Saludos